# WPF Binding with Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I have in WPF a combobox this way:

```
combobox.ItemsSource = await clientelocal.ObtenerVariablesAsync();
combobox.DisplayMemberPath = "Nombre";
```

In `DisplayMemberPath` I want to have two fields, something like:

```
combobox.ItemsSource = await clientelocal.ObtenerVariablesAsync();
combobox.DisplayMemberPath = "ID + Nombre";
```

but not how to do it, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the collection just like your doing but don't set the DisplayMemberPath. Here is an example:

MyComboBox.ItemsSource = await clientelocal.ObtenerVariablesAsync();

Then do this in the XAML:

```
<ComboBox Name="MyComboBox">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nombre}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

The key is that item template, you can do whatever you like in there to change the look of the items, give them color, change the padding through margins etc...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting `DisplayMemberPath`, you need to define custom `ItemTemplate` to display more than one properties :

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nombre}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```